# Straight line passes through a circle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In a rectangular coordinate system, there is a circle $x^2 + y^2 -12 x+4 y-9=0$ and a straight line.  If the straight line passes through $A(-2,-3)$ and intersects the circle at point $B$ and $C$, find the value of $A B \times A C$.

The given solution is this: $A B \times A C=\left(\sqrt{(-2)^{2}+(-3)^{2}-12(-2)+4(-3)-9}\right)^{2}=\left(\sqrt{16}\right)^{2}= \boxed{16}$

It looks like we simply substitute the values $(-2, -3)$ into the equation for the circle and find the square root of the result. How come? I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can interpret the left-hand side of the circle equation, scaled such that the highest order terms are precisely $x^2+y^2$, as a function from points to real values, the so-called [power function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) with respect to the given circle. The problem can be answered with the [intersecting secants theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point#Intersecting_secants_theorem,_intersecting_chords_theorem): $AB\cdot AC$ equals the power of $A$.